# Why does my tablet reset every time I reboot?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, factory-reset, prestigio-multipad

I bought a tablet a few days ago.

I was playing around with a wireless mouse and a USB OTG cable and decided to restart the tablet for some reason (I don't remember why). After that, when the device booted I saw the setup wizard that started when the tablet was turned on for the first time.

The device now resets whenever I reboot, and I can't download & install apps from Play (error says that theres no memory), and I cannot enter recovery mode.

Device: Prestigio PMP3270B 
Android: 4.0.3

Answer (score 2):

All problems from busybox bad installation path..
Solution from here http://tabletrepublic.com/forum/teclast-a10t/factory-reset-after-every-restart-shutdown-1533-2.html

If device isn't root you should root it .Used Unlock Root and Tasselhof Market.
Also downloaded & copied Root Explorer to microSD.
Install and run it.
Go to /system/xbin and find busybox.
Move it to /system/bin
reboot & profit

All download links are on that forum